# Difference between Occurrence and Instance in iCalendar standard?

Tags: standards, icalendar, caldav, rfc5545

Are there any difference between terms "occurrence" and "instance" in iCalendar [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)?

I found that CalDAV [RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791) is using term "instance" only, there is no term "occurrence" used in it.

It looks like these are synonyms or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that (in the context) an 'occurrence' is a point in time calculated by an RRULE.

An 'instance' is an actual event, which would show up in the calendar. Either an instance produced by a recurring event, or an individual event.

Not every 'occurrence' of a recurring event has to end up in an instance. Usually because individual instances got deleted, but the RFC seems to suggest other, timezone related situations in which occurrences get dropped.

Sample:

```
DTSTART:20160107
RRULE;FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5
EXDATE:20160109
```

Presumably 2016-01-09 would be called an occurrence of the RRULE, but it is not an actual instance (5 occurrences, 4 instances).

But as Marten says it is probably not very relevant and potentially not even used consistently in the RFC ;->
Maybe you could explain the point of your question, is there something more to it?

Comment: My team argues about the name of the method that expands event/to-do/journal into instances. It must take into account EXDATE. So probably GetInstances() would be the right name.

Comment: I suppose it would be GetInstancesInTimeRange(from, to) as you can't calculate all instances in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

RFC 5545 uses `occurrence` only in the context of recurring events (if you don't count the statements about the number of occurrences of certain properties/values). So you could argue that an `occurrence` is an `instance` of a recurring event.
You probably wouldn't refer to a single event as an `occurrence`.

The Oxford dictionary says about [`instance`](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/englisch/instance):

> An example or **single occurrence** of something

(emphasis by me)

This kind of supports the conclusion above.

However, I think with regards to the specs this distinction is pretty much irrelevant.